# Beazley 4e P.E.R pg 135,136: for c in sub.mro?

Tags: python, method-resolution-order

What exactly does the last line of IClass do??

**subclasscheck** overloads subclasscheck but, normally while
overloading an operator we do something like:

> adt + 4.0
>   here, adt is the user defined type = user class object(instance) and 4.0
>   is a builtin type which has say .real, .imaginary pre-configured so if
>   adt is complex then this becomes:
>   adt.(self, other)
>   **add**(self, other)
>   so a reference to 'adt' is generated and fed to 'self' and 'other' refers 
>   to 4.0

But in the example below:

```
class IClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.implementors = set()
    def register(self,C):
        self.implementors.add(C)
    def __instancecheck__(self,x):
        return self.__subclasscheck__(type(x))
    def __subclasscheck__(self,sub):
        return any(c in self.implementors for c in sub.mro())

# Now, use the above object
IFoo = IClass()
IFoo.register(Foo)
IFoo.register(FooProxy)

f = Foo()           # Create a Foo
g = FooProxy(f)     # Create a FooProxy
isinstance(f, IFoo)        # Returns True
isinstance(g, IFoo)        # Returns True
issubclass(FooProxy, IFoo) # Returns True
```

Here what are self and sub for **subclasscheck**?? How is
**subclasscheck** being overloaded??

Anyway, assuming it is being overloaded somehow.. a reference to FooProxy is 
passed to self and IFoo->sub. So.. IFoo.mro() would generate the method
resolution order for instance IFoo and therefore for IClass.. which
would be just object.. umm.. wth??

Could somone explain what is going on here?? Basically 'any' should return
True if FooProxy is a sub-class of the grouped-classes in IClass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__subclasscheck__` is the method to override built-in `issubclass`.
The call `issubclass(X,Y)` first checks whether `Y.__subclasscheck__` exists, and if so, calls `Y.__subclasscheck__(X)` instead of its normal implementation. 

similarly;`__instancecheck__` is the method to override built-in `isinstance`. The call `isinstance(X, Y)` first checks whether 
`Y.__instancecheck__` exists, and if so, calls `Y.__instancecheck__(X)` 
instead of its normal implementation.

```
In [121]: class FooProxy3(object):
     ...:     pass

In [122]: issubclass(FooProxy3,IFoo)
Out[122]: False

In [123]: for c in IFoo.implementors:
     ...:     print c
     ...:     
<class '__main__.Foo'>
<class '__main__.FooProxy'>

In [124]: for c in FooProxy3.mro():
     ...:     print c
     ...:     
<class '__main__.FooProxy3'>
<type 'object'>

In [125]: IFoo.register(FooProxy3)

In [126]: for c in IFoo.implementors:
     ...:     print c
     ...:     
<class '__main__.Foo'>
<class '__main__.FooProxy'>
<class '__main__.FooProxy3'>

In [127]: issubclass(FooProxy3,IFoo)
Out[127]: True
```

lets consider above example;create new class `FooProxy3`; and check `issubclass` for that; and it will return `False` (as per `Out[122]`) because we are looking for subclass check in `IFoo.implementors`; and there it is not present (as per `In[123]`)
but when we have `register` `FooProxy`(here it means; now we can see it `IFoo.implementors`); we can see it `Foxproxy3` in `IFoo.implementors` (as per `In[126]`)
so when we check `issubclass` ; it wil return `True`. 

for more info;
[Customizing instance and subclass checks](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__subclasscheck__#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks)

[Overloading isinstance() and issubclass()](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/#overloading-isinstance-and-issubclass)

Comment: umm.. need to ponder this some more. I'm not happy with the answer though.. I still don;t understand why he needs to look at all the base classes of the instance and check it against implementors. ABC's are supposed to group classes.. so class of instance should be matched against implementors and that's it..